# Malformed Json while load from file

Tags: android, json, malformed

when I load some mock data from a .json file in resources sometimes the data is returned corrupted and shows �������������������� symbols. But actual data does not have these symbols. The code I tried to load is below any idea why this happen? Thanks

```
fun loadJSONFromAsset(fileName: String): String? {
        val json: String
        try {
            val `is` = javaClass.classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName)

            val size = `is`.available()
            val buffer = ByteArray(size)
            `is`.read(buffer)
            `is`.close()
            json = String(buffer, Charset.defaultCharset())
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
            return null
        }
        return json
    }
```

Comment: show your mock data

Answer (score 2):

Files that are not compressed on their own will be compressed when put inside the asset folder. You must either open your file with AssetManager

```
val jsonString = context
    .assets
    .open("myfile.json")
    .bufferedReader()
    .readText()
```

or disable compression for `.json` files at build time.

```
android {
    aaptOptions {
       noCompress 'json'
    }
}
```

Besides, I don't think you would ever have a good reason to open files bundled in the apk with `classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName)`, on Android you can use `AssetManager` or `Resources`. I just found this [interesting article](http://blog.nimbledroid.com/2016/04/06/slow-ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream.html), it shows that using getResourceAsStream can be also very slow.